# Find string in file and perform math on part in Linux

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I'm trying to find a string in a file, and when I find that string break it up and perform math on part of it.  It sounds like `sed` won't work because I want to do math and `awk` will be difficult because I want to update the file in place.

My file looks like this (is an svn diff)

```
Index: code/foo.c
===================================================================
--- code/foo.c  (revision 13)
+++ code/foo.c  (working copy)
@@ -3,5 +3,5 @@
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     printf("I don't like being moved around!\n%s", bar());
-    return 0;
+    return 1;
 }
```

I'm looking for the `@@` line and want to add 1 to the last number before the ending `@@`.  So, `@@ -3,5 +3,5 @@` would become `@@ -3,5 +3,6 @@`

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: Changing the offsets alone will invalidate the diff. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: @tripleee We have an internal tool that merges changes to different branches.  But we track changes "differently" across the branches, so I'm inserting a comment to say the automated tool made the change then patching that in.  (I already figured out how to insert the comment where needed (which does invalidate the diff), so I'm trying to fix that up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
/^@@.*@@/{
  split($NF,array," ")
  $NF=array[1]+1" " array[2]
}
1
'   Input_file
```

In case in you want to save output into Input_file then append `> temp_file  && mv temp_file  Input_file` in above code too.

***NOTE:*** In case you are using GNU `awk` >= 4.1.0 does have an `-i inplace` in it too.

Comment: +1. Just as a point on interest, according to the posix docs, "_All elements of the array shall be deleted before the split is performed._" (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13), so probably the `delete` isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: @jas, sure thanks jas, I have put it in case of $NF is null or not having any values then it shouldn't print previous array's values let me change its place before `split` now.

Comment: That's the point; you don't have to worry about that. Try this: `awk 'BEGIN {split("x y z", a); print length(a); split("", a); print length(a)}'`

Comment: @jas, cool got it, I have deleted it now, cheers and thanks for letting know.

Comment: Maybe also mention that GNU Awk >= 4.1.0 does have an `-i inplace` option. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-in-place

Comment: @tripleee, added GNU `awk` information too now in my post, thanks for letting know.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/^(@@.*,)([0-9]+)( @@)$/,a){$0=a[1] a[2]+1 a[3]} 1' file
Index: code/foo.c
===================================================================
--- code/foo.c  (revision 13)
+++ code/foo.c  (working copy)
@@ -3,5 +3,6 @@
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     printf("I don't like being moved around!\n%s", bar());
-    return 0;
+    return 1;
 }
```