# Using sed to replace a part of a string that is unknown

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a text file:

**example.txt**

```
UserName = JIU62H123;
USER_NAME = JIU62H123;
```

I need to change `JIU62H123` to `A5B4C6DF9`. Obviously, for this file I could just do:

```
//bash
sed -i '' 's/JIU62H123/A5B4C6DF9/g' example.txt
```

This works for this file as you can see from the result:

**example.txt**

```
UserName = A5B4C6DF9;
USER_NAME = A5B4C6DF9;
```

However, in actuality, I won't know if the username is actually ahead of time. All I know is that the file is in this shape:

**example.txt**

```
UserName = <some_letters_and_numbers>;
USER_NAME = <some_letters_and_numbers>;
```

I basically need to change `<some_letters_and_numbers>` to `A5B4C6DF9`. Can this be done with one or more `sed` commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks very much for the answers, upvoted each one. I ended up doing a solution like so:

```
sed -i '' -E 's/(DEVELOPMENT_TEAM|DevelopmentTeam)( = )(.*)/\1\2A5B4C6DF9;/' example.txt
```

Most of the answers given here seemed to be matching for a pattern of letters/numbers, but I think it might be better to match against anything and replace it with the desired content.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a regex?

```sh
sed -ir 's/^(USER_NAME|UserName) = [A-Za-z0-9]+;$/\1 = A5B4C6DF9;/g' example.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

#### In real words:

- on lines  begining by `UserName` or `USER_NAME`, followed by equal sign `=`,
- replace right hand side by ...

#### In `sed` syntax:

Using *variable* for adaptability

```
newId=A5B4C6DF9
sed -e '/^U\(serName\|\SER_NAME) *=/s/= .*$/'$newId/ -i example.txt
```

**Nota** The quoted part end just before the variable!

This work until `$newId` don't contain special chars. If variable could contain *spaces* or other non alphanumeric characters, use double-quotes:

```
sed -e '/^U\(serName\|\SER_NAME) *=/s/= .*$/'"$newId"/ -i example.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk you could:

```
$ awk '{$3="A5B4C6DF9;"}1' file
UserName = A5B4C6DF9;
USER_NAME = A5B4C6DF9;
```

ie. replace the 3rd space separated field. With a [recent enough GNU awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16531920/4162356]) you could do an inplace edit:

```
$ awk -i inplace '{$3="A5B4C6DF9;"}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

To `change <some_letters_and_numbers> to A5B4C6DF9` and assuming you meant to add `on the right side of "= "` with a sed that has `-E` for EREs is:

```
$ sed -E 's/= [[:alnum:]]+/= A5B4C6DF9/' file
UserName = A5B4C6DF9;
USER_NAME = A5B4C6DF9;
```

and with any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/= [[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]*/= A5B4C6DF9/' file
UserName = A5B4C6DF9;
USER_NAME = A5B4C6DF9;
```