# change date format in a file linux

Tags: linux, awk

I have a csv file. I need to change the date format in the data inside the file.

```
ABCD,1234,01022019
```

I tried the following:

```
awk -F ',' '{printf("%s,%s,",$1,$2);system("date -d "$3" +%Y-%m-%d");}' new
```

I need to change the date format in that file, not to write to another file.

Comment: Please do post expected output in your post within code tags and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean you want to change the source file so that those dates are of the `yyyy-mm-dd` format, you can do that with `awk` on its own:

```
awk -F, '{$3 = substr($3,5,4)"-"substr($3,3,2)"-"substr($3,1,2) ; print}' inFile >outFile
```

You can then check to make sure the line count is the same before copying back over the original, something like:

```
[[ $(wc -l <<inFile) -eq $(wc -l <<outFile) ]] && mv outFile inFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply arrange the substrings from the date in a different order.

If you have Linux, chances are you have GNU Awk version 4.1 or newer, which has the option `inplace` so you can write the result back to the original file. (See also [Save modifications in place with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/save-modifications-in-place-with-awk))

```
awk -F, -i inplace '{ $3 = substr($3, 5) "-" substr($3, 3, 2) "-" substr($3, 1, 2) }1' datadata.csv
```