# Add / Insert xml tags into existing xml file using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have an XML file abc.xml that I want to configure using a bash script. For example, if I had this abc.xml:

```
<a>

  <b>
    <bb>
        <yyy>
            Bla 
        </yyy>
    </bb>
  </b>

  <c>
    <cc>
      Something
    </cc>
  </c>

  <d>
    bla
  </d>
</a>
```

And another xyz.xml file

```
    <xxx>
        <yyy>
            <ggg>
                <hhh>true</hhh>
                <kkk>always</kkk>
                <mmm>warn</mmm>
            </ggg>
            <id>repo</id>
            <url>https://repository/repo-2.0/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </yyy> 
    </xxx>
```

After `</b>`and before `<c>`  tag in abc.xml file. I need to insert all the tags in file xyz.xml.
I'm new to shell scripting.
Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will of course fail if `Bla` or `Something` or other tags etc. includes `<c>`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {                 # process xyz
    b=b (b==""?"":ORS) $0        # buffer its lines
    next
}
match($0,/ *<c>/) {              # look for <c>
    print substr($0,1,RSTART-1)  # print up to it
    print b                      # print buffer
    print substr($0,RSTART)      # print from tag on
    next 
}1' xyz abc
```

**Edit**: Small awk primer:

In `NR==FNR{...;next}` block you process the first given file, `xyz` in this case. `ORS` is the *output record separator* ie. newline that defaults to `\n`.

Comment: Thank you for your time and response. How can I debug the above script you shared?

Comment: You can use for example [GNU awk' debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Debugger.html) or add `print [what you want to see] > "debug_file_name.txt"`after evry line which you want to debug.

Comment: Please guide me If I missed something, In the last line of the script when I do xyz abc > pqr I get the expected output in pqr. However, I want to modify the original file which is abc in this case. Could you please help. Thanks!

Comment: The answers to this question explain it (depending on your awk version): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/save-modifications-in-place-with-awk . Don't forget to upvote the authors in there!

Comment: what if I need to search one level deeper e.g. ``` <c>
    <cc>
       <ccc>something</ccc>
    </cc>
  </c> ``` in abc.xml file

Comment: If it's anything ahrder than _replace this with something else_ you should use some kind of xml parser tool.

Comment: Thank you.I request you guide me if I missed something when I add                        
```  awk -i inplace ``` it deletes all the content from the xyz.xml file.

Comment: Yes, `xyz` will be empty.

Comment: How can I make use of awk to match multiple lines?

Comment: What does that even mean? Please, post another question with proper explanation,  sample dataset and related expected output.

Comment: I added a question here with an explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65125890/how-to-match-multiple-line-in-xml-using-awk-in-shell-script

Comment: Could you please help me to resolve?