# Duplicate first column of multiple text files in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have multiple text files each containing two columns and I would like to duplicate the first column in each file in bash to have three columns in the end.

File:

```
sP100227 1
sP100267 1
sP100291 1
sP100493 1
```

Output file:

```
sP100227 sP100227 1
sP100267 sP100267 1
sP100291 sP100291 1
sP100493 sP100493 1
```

I tried:

```
txt=path/to/*.txt
echo "$(paste <(cut -f1-2 $txt) > "$txt"
```

Comment: Why are you using `-d','`? Your file isn't comma-separated.

Comment: you can't use the same file as input and output. The output redirection truncates the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default delimiter in `cut` and `paste` is TAB, but your file looks to be space-separated.

You can't use the same file as input and output redirection, because when the shell opens the file for output it truncates it, so there's nothing for the program to read. Write to a new file and then rename it.

Your `paste` command is only being given one input file. And there's no need to use `echo`.

```
paste -d' ' <(cut -d' ' -f1 "$txt") "$txt" > "$txt.new" && mv "$txt.new" "$txt"
```

You can do this more easily using `awk`.

```
awk '{print $1, $0}' "$txt" > "$txt.new" && mv "$txt.new" "$txt"
```

GNU awk has an in-place extension, so you can use that if you like. See [Save modifications in place with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/save-modifications-in-place-with-awk)

Comment: `for txt in file1 file2 ...`

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. This will add fields to only those lines which have 2 fields in it.

```
awk 'NF==2{$1=$1 OFS $1} 1' Input_file
```

In case you don't care of number of fields and simply want to have value of 1st field 2 times then try following.

```
awk '{$1=$1 OFS $1} 1' Input_file
```

---

OR if you only have 2 fields in your Input_file then we need not to rewrite the complete line we could simply print them as follows.

```
awk '{print $1,$1,$2}' Input_file
```

To save output into same Input_file itself append  `> temp && mv temp Input_file` for above solutions(after testing).

Answer (score 3):

Use a temp file, with `cut -f1` and `paste`, like so:

```
paste <(cut -f1 in_file) in_file > tmp_file
mv tmp_file in_file
```

Alternatively, use a Perl one-liner, like so:

```
perl -i.bak -lane 'print join "\t", $F[0], $_;' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Answer (score 1):

Try `sed -Ei 's/\s*(\S+)\s+/\1 \1 /1' $txt` if your fields are separated by strings of one or more whitespace characters. This used the Stream Editor (`sed`) replaces (`s///1`) the first string of non-space characters (`\S+`) followed by a string of whitespace characters (`\s+`) with the same thing repeated with intervening spaces(`\1 \1` ). It keeps the rest of the line. The `-E` to `sed` means use extended pattern matching (`+`, `(` vs. `\(`). The `-i` means do it in-place, replacing the file with the output.

You could use `awk` and do `awk '{ printf "%s %s\n",$1,$0 }'`. This takes the first whitespace-delimited field (`$1`) and follows it with a space and the whole line (`$0`) followed by a newline. This is a little clearer than `sed` but it doesn't have the advantage of being in-place.

If you can guarantee they are delimited by only one space, with no leading spaces, you can use `paste -d' ' <(cut -d' ' -f1 ${txt}) ${txt} > ${txt}.new; mv ${txt}.new ${txt}`. The `-d' '` sets the delimiter to space for both `cut` and `paste`. You know this but for others `-f1` means extract the first `-d`-delimited field. The `mv` command replaces the input with the output.