# AWK remove blank lines and append empty columns to all csv files in the directory

Tags: bash, csv, awk

Hi I am looking for a way to combine all the below commands together.

1. Remove blank lines in the csv file (comma delimited)
2. Add multiple empty columns to each line up to 100th column
3. Perform action 1 & 2 on all the files in the folder

I am still learning and this is the best I could get:

```
awk '!/^[[:space:]]*$/' x.csv > tmp && mv tmp x.csv
```

```
awk -F"," '($100="")1' OFS="," x.csv > tmp && mv tmp x.csv
```

They work out individually but I don't know how how to put them together and I am looking for ways to have it run through all the files under the directory.

**Looking for concrete AWK code or shell script calling AWK.**
Thank you!

An example input would be:

```
a,b,c

x,y,z
```

Expected output would be:

```
a,b,c,,,,,,,,,,
x,y,z,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output. Don't post them as comments or images. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can combine in one script without any loops

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==1{close(f); f=FILENAME".updated"} NF{$100=""; print > f}' files...
```

it won't overwrite the original files.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output of the first to the other:

```
awk '!/^[[:space:]]*$/' x.csv | awk -F"," '($100="")1' OFS="," > new_x.csv
```

If you wanted to run the above on all the files in your directory, you would do:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in yourdirectory/*.csv; do
  awk '!/^[[:space:]]*$/' "${f}" | awk -F"," '($100="")1' OFS="," > new_"${f}"
done
```

The `shopt -s nullglob` is so that an empty directory won't give you a literal `*`. Quoted from [a good source for about looping through files](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 0):

With [recent enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16531920/4162356) GNU awk you could:

```
$ gawk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}/\S/{NF=100;$1=$1;print}' *
```

Explained:

```
$ gawk -i inplace '   # using GNU awk and in-place file editing
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","        # set delimiters to a comma
}
/\S/ {                # gawk specific regex operator that matches any character that is not a space
    NF=100            # set the field count to 100 which truncates fields above it
    $1=$1             # edit the first field to rebuild the record to actually get the extra commas
    print             # output records
}' *
```

Some test data (the first empty record is empty, the second empty record has a space and a tab, trust me bro):

```
$ cat file
1,2,3

  
1,2,3,4,5,6,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101
```

Output of `cat file` after the execution of the GNU awk program:

```
1,2,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,2,3,4,5,6,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100
```