# Insert or update a row in a text file

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I want to write a value to a text file with a timestamp. The data/value gets updated every few minutes, but I only want to record the last value and its date. The next day I want to start again with a new line but keeping the previous value. The output will then be charted showing daily values.

I can do this with an if, then, else loop, but I imagine there's a more elegant awk, sed, 'something' solution.

This will be run by a cron job.

**Day 1.**
Every 5 minutes insert a row with $date, $value

During the same day keep updating that row

**Day 2.**
Insert a new row and repeat

*Desired output*

**Day 1 10am**

```
2021-08-17, 5.20
```

**Day 1 11pm**

```
2021-08-17, 12.10
```

**Day 2 10am**

```
2021-08-17, 12.10
2021-08-18, 4.90
```

**Day 2 11pm**

```
2021-08-17, 12.10
2021-08-18, 13.10
```

Comment: what (code) have you tried so far?

Comment: _I can do this with an if, then, else loop_  There is no _if-then-else-loop_. Loops in bash are done using _for_, _while_ or _select_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea would be to skip/ignore/delete the line with today's date (if it exists) and then append a new line with today's date.

Sample data file:

```
$ cat date.log
2021-08-14, 23.1
2021-08-15, 17.3
2021-08-16, 9.3

$ today=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
$ echo $today
2021-08-17

$ newvalue=13.2
```

One `sed` idea to implement this logic:

```
$ sed -i -n -e "/^${today}, .*$/"'!p' -e '$a'"${today}, ${newvalue}" date.log
```

Where:

- `-i -n -e` - `-i`nplace update of source file, `-n` suppress automatic printing of pattern space, `-e` designate a piece of script
- `"/^${today}, .*$/"` - search for pattern that matches (start of line) + `${today}` + `,`  + rest of line; need to use double quotes so that `${today}` is replaced with it's actual value
- `'!p'` - reverse pattern search and print line (ie, print everything but line that matches `^${today}, .*$`); need to use single quotes since `!p` in double quotes will be replaced with the last history command that started with the letter `p`
- `-e '$a'` - another piece of script that finds end of file (`$`) and `a`ppends the following string; must use single quotes so that `bash` doesn't try to replace the literal `$a` with the contents of variable `a`
- `"${today}, ${newvalue}"` - string to append to end of file

If we preface our `sed` call with `set -xv` (enable debug mode) we see the following is printed at the console:

```
+ sed -i -n -e '/^2021-08-17, .*$/!p' -e '$a2021-08-17, 13.2' date.log
```

And the contents of our file:

```
$ cat date.log
2021-08-14, 23.1
2021-08-15, 17.3
2021-08-16, 9.3
2021-08-17, 13.2              # new line appended to file
```

A couple more runs (after issuing `set +xv` to disable debug mode):

```
$ newvalue=32.7
$ sed -i -n -e "/^${today}, .*$/"'!p' -e '$a'"${today}, ${newvalue}" date.log
$ cat date.log
2021-08-14, 23.1
2021-08-15, 17.3
2021-08-16, 9.3
2021-08-17, 32.7              # updated (really deleted and appended)

$ newvalue=73.xxx
$ sed -i -n -e "/^${today}, .*$/"'!p' -e '$a'"${today}, ${newvalue}" date.log
$ cat date.log
2021-08-14, 23.1
2021-08-15, 17.3
2021-08-16, 9.3
2021-08-17, 73.xxx            # updated (really deleted and appended)

$ today='2021-09-23'
$ newvalue=7.25
$ sed -i -n -e "/^${today}, .*$/"'!p' -e '$a'"${today}, ${newvalue}" date.log
$ cat date.log
2021-08-14, 23.1
2021-08-15, 17.3
2021-08-16, 9.3
2021-08-17, 73.xxx
2021-09-23, 7.25              # new line appended to file
```

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso - that's just what I was after. And thank you for the detailed and clear explanation - much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use two different cronjob entries. One that runs at the start of each day that adds a new row to the file with `ed` or whatever:

```sh
# Something that sets date and value here
printf "%s\n" '$a' "$date, $value" . w | ed -s /your/file.txt
```

And another that runs every 5 minutes and replaces the current last line of the file with a new value:

```sh
# Something that sets date and value here
printf "%s\n" '$c' "$date, $value" . w | ed -s /your/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`-i inplace` capable version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16531920/4162356) of GNU awk:

```
$ gawk -i inplace -v d=2021-08-17 -v v=12.20 '    # new data in parameters
@load "filefuncs"                                 # for stat to detect missing file
BEGIN {
    if(ARGC==1)                                   # if no file given
        exit 1                                    # exit with an error
    FS=OFS=", "                                   # set the field separators
    # d=strftime("%F")                            # no need parameterize the date
    if(stat(ARGV[1],fdata)<0) {                   # if given file does not exist
        print d,v > ARGV[1]                       # create it
        exit                                      # and exit
    }
}
{
    if(NR>1)                                  
        print pd,pv                               # print previous data record
    pd=$1                                         # store current for next round
    pv=$2
}
ENDFILE {                                         # in the end
    if(pd!=d)                                     # if dates differ
        print pd,pv                               # print previous
    print d,v                                     # print given data
    exit                                          # to skip over following files
}' file
```