# AWK populating an empty column with AWK and Sed is not working

Tags: awk, sed, xargs, txt

I have the following file called stack1.txt:

```
        Date    Item    Amount
        2020-01-23      Petrol  -160
        2020-03-24      Electricity     -200
        2020-04-24      Electricity     -200
        2020-05-30      Trim line       -50
        2021-03-11      Martha Burns    150
        2021-03-14      Highbury shops  300
```

I created an empty column at $1 that I wish to populate so the negative amounts in column $4 get a "c" in column $1, such as

```
        Date    Item    Amount
c       2020-01-23      Petrol  -160
c       2020-03-24      Electricity     -200
c       2020-04-24      Electricity     -200
c       2020-05-30      Trim line       -50
        2021-03-11      Martha Burns    150
        2021-03-14      Highbury shops  300
```

I have tried the following command:

```
awk -F '\t' '$4 < 0 {print $1}' stack1.txt | xargs -r sed -i 's//c/g'
```

If I `cat stack1.txt` I still get an unchanged table as above. Originally I used xargs without -r and got `sed: no input files`. -r removed this. I also tried `'s/""/c/g'`. I am trying to save the altered output back to stack1.txt hence `sed -i`. I am however at a loss why this does not work. Appreciate some help on this.

Comment: My field separator is a single tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" } $4<0{ $1="c" }1' file
```

Output:

```
        Date    Item    Amount
c       2020-01-23      Petrol  -160
c       2020-03-24      Electricity     -200
c       2020-04-24      Electricity     -200
c       2020-05-30      Trim line       -50
        2021-03-11      Martha Burns    150
        2021-03-14      Highbury shops  300
```

See: [Save modifications in place with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16529716/3776858)

Comment: Why 1 after the curly bracket?

Comment: `awk` evaluates `1` as `true` and therefore it prints `$0`. Long version: `{ print }`

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question 'why this does not work", you should test the components of your pipeline one by one.

```
awk -F '\t' '$4 < 0 {print $1}' stack1.txt
```

prints four empty lines, one for every line with negative column 4 of the original file. Nothing can `xargs` and `sed` do with this output to get the effect you want.  The input for `xargs sed -i ...` must be a list of files. The whole attempt is unfortunate.

See [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus) answer for an alternative, or

```
perl -i.bak -aple 's/^/c/ if $F[-1]<0' stack1.txt
```

which works with arbitrary mix of tabs and spaces as separators.