# script/command to add extra space before stating of selected/each line in a paragraph

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I need to update my cpp source files header by adding extra one space before starting of the below lines in header information -

```
This file is an example header file.
There are 100 files are present with this formats.
Some files are with proper space before starting of each line in this paragraph.
How to move each line in this paragraph with single space at start using any script.
All above lines are fixed throughout all files.
```

**Present Header format:**

```
/*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ FileHeaderBegin +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

 ALL INFORMATION ARE BELONGS TO ABCDEF
 Copyright 2015 - 2020 ABCDEF LTD
 All Rights Reserved

This file is an example header file.
There are 100 files are present with this formats.
Some files are with proper space before starting of each line in this paragraph.
How to move each line in this paragraph with single space at start using any script.
All above lines are fixed throughout all files.

 *++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 *
 * FILENAME: test.cpp
 *
 * DESCRIPTION: Sample file for command test
 *
 *++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ FileHeaderEnd +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
```

**Expected:**

```
/*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ FileHeaderBegin +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

 ALL INFORMATION ARE BELONGS TO ABCDEF
 Copyright 2015 - 2020 ABCDEF LTD
 All Rights Reserved

 This file is an example header file.
 There are 100 files are present with this formats.
 Some files are with proper space before starting of each line in this paragraph.
 How to move each line in this paragraph with single space at start using any script.
 All above lines are fixed throughout all files.

 *++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 *
 * FILENAME: test.cpp
 *
 * DESCRIPTION: Sample file for command test
 *
 *++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ FileHeaderEnd +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
```

**Query:**
Is there any command or script available to do that changes.
I have total 270 files with few files with proper space added and majority files with no space added.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/FileHeaderBegin/{:a;n;s/^\S/ &/;/FileHeaderEnd/!ba}' file1 ... filen
```

Turn on edit inplace option `-i`

Insert a space at the front of any line that begins with a non-space character between the lines containing `FileHeaderBegin` and `FileHeaderEnd`.

Alternative solution:

```
sed -i '/FileHeaderBegin/,/FileHeaderEnd/s/^\S/ &/' file1 ... filen
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/^[[:space:]]/ ! s/^/ /' input_file
 /*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ FileHeaderBegin +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

 ALL INFORMATION ARE BELONGS TO ABCDEF
 Copyright 2015 - 2020 ABCDEF LTD
 All Rights Reserved

 This file is an example header file.
 There are 100 files are present with this formats.
 Some files are with proper space before starting of each line in this paragraph.
 How to move each line in this paragraph with single space at start using any script.
 All above lines are fixed throughout all files.

 *++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 *
 * FILENAME: test.cpp
 *
 * DESCRIPTION: Sample file for command test
 *
 *++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ FileHeaderEnd +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file header always looks like that you can do the following with GNU awk:

```
awk '(FNR==1){h=0}(!h && !/^ /){$0=" " $0}/*\//{h++}1' file
```

You can now put this in a loop to process your files.

This awk script searches for the string "*/" which appears for the first time right after the header. Only until this string is found, we check for lines that mis the space at the beginning.

For inplace modifications with awk: see [Save modifications in place with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/save-modifications-in-place-with-awk)