# Find word in text by ID and replace other word in the same line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have crontab with some rules. I need to find a line with server ID, and then replace the number of days at the end of the line.

```
$ crontab -l
00 6 * * * /home/scripts/User/19122391_User_Server_Notification_shutdown_delete.sh 64
00 16 * * * /home/scripts/User/20045967_User_Server_Notification_shutdown_delete.sh 15
```

ID of server: `19122391`
Days: `64`

So, I need to change number `64` to another, for example 100 in `crontab`. To find a line I use this command `awk '/19122391/{print}' crontab.bak`, but how to replace last number in line, I did not can find solutions.

**Can I use bash script to do this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -i inplace '/19122391/{$NF=100}1' crontab.bak
00 6 * * * /home/scripts/User/19122391_User_Server_Notification_shutdown_delete.sh 100
00 16 * * * /home/scripts/User/20045967_User_Server_Notification_shutdown_delete.sh 15
```

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -i '/19122391/s/[0-9]*$/100/' crontab.bak
00 6 * * * /home/scripts/User/19122391_User_Server_Notification_shutdown_delete.sh 100
00 16 * * * /home/scripts/User/20045967_User_Server_Notification_shutdown_delete.sh 15
```

Comment: Thank you, but after this command my crontab does not have changes. Main goal is to change number in file.

Comment: @Oleg use inplace edit. I will update answer to include it

Comment: GNU awk and inplace edit, OB. link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16531920/4162356

Comment: @HatLess Thank you, it works!!! :) And can I use this command also with crontab, not with test file crontab.bak?

Comment: @Oleg You can use the specific user cronfile found under `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`

Comment: @HatLess Cool!!! Thank you very much! And one last moment, could you please explain, what does it mean `1` in command `awk -i inplace '/19122391/{$NF=100}1'`

Comment: @Oleg It is a shorthand to the `{print}` command.

Comment: @HatLess Hello, could you please tell me, Is it possible using this command to plus amount of days. For example, if I have 64 days and I need more 10 days, can I make in command to find 64 days and make plus 10 days?

Comment: @Oleg Apologies, I have only just noticed your last comment. What you have asked should be possible, but I'd advise a new question so you can show sample data of exactly what you mean and get a focused answer.