# how do I replace a information Fromm csv file?

Tags: bash, csv

I have the following program

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3< lista.csv
read -u 3 header
declare -i id_nou
echo "ID: "
read id_nou
while IFS=, && read -u 3 -r id nume prenume seria grupa nota
do
if [ "$id_nou" -eq "$id" ]
then
echo "Nota noua: "
read  nota_noua
nota=$nota_noua
print > lista.csv
fi
done
```

My csv file looks something like this:

```
id,nume,prenume,grupa,seria,nota

1,Ion,Andrada,1003,A,8

2,Simion,Raluca,1005,A,7

3,Gheorghita,Mihail,1009,B,5

4,Mihailescu,Georgina,1002,A,6
```

What I'm trying to do is replace the nota value of the correspondent's id with a given by the keyboard value, but this doesn't seem to work.
The error message is

line 14: print: command not found

Comment: `print` is not a builtin program of bash. What did you want to do with it? `zsh` has an internal  command of this name.

Comment: ok so what can I write instead?

Comment: What effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: well my csv file has this format: id,name,surname,group,serie,grade. I want to change the grade value of a given id

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: My question was: What was the supposed effect of your `print` statement? After all, you got an error message for this statement.

Comment: I meant to overwrite the whole line, with the modified value of nota over the current line

Comment: Why are you using `while/read`?  This is trivial with `awk`.

Comment: Don't try to modify the input file during the loop.  Write the output somewhere else (a temporary file) and overwrite the original at the end.

Comment: thank you. do you know what command should I use to overwrite at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one in awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","                            # comma field separators
    printf "id: "                         # ask for id
    if((getline id < "/dev/stdin")<=0)    # store to a variable
        exit 1
    printf "nota: "                       # ...
    if((getline nota < "/dev/stdin")<=0)
        exit 1
}
$1==id {                                  # if firsst field matches
    $NF=nota                              # replace last field value
}
1' file                                   # output
```

Output:

```
id: 1
nota: THIS IS NEW VALUE
id,nume,prenume,grupa,seria,nota
1,Ion,Andrada,1003,A,THIS IS NEW VALUE
2,Simion,Raluca,1005,A,7
3,Gheorghita,Mihail,1009,B,5
4,Mihailescu,Georgina,1002,A,6
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16529716/4162356) is some info on saving the changes.

Comment: I haven't figured out how to change the changes, can you help me out please?

Comment: If you are using GNU awk: `gawk -i inplace ...`, else `awk ... file > tmp && mv tmp file`.